# How to Access App Delegate from Binary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, binary, uiapplicationdelegate, appdelegate

I want to access the App delegate in an iPhone app. I can do this from code either in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)
```

or

```
NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> *appDelegate = (NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Is there any way to access the App Delegate from the binary of an application instead of using Objective-C source code?

Comment: What are you doing messing with Binary?

Comment: This question doesn't quite make sense. What do you mean by 'accessing it from binary'?

Comment: I need this in cases when I don't have the source code and only have the binary of the application. So my question is if I only have binary of an application, is there anyway to access the app delegate object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need this in cases when I don't have the source code and only have
> the binary of the application. So my question is if I only have binary
> of an application, is there anyway to access the app delegate object?

## NO

### You can not.